# Error trying to get authenticated user email with googleapis and node.js

Tags: google-authentication, google-api-nodejs-client, google-people-api

I'm implementing auth on my website using googleapis. The function plus.people.get doesn't work. I have seen it is deprecated on some forums but it's still documented at google which has me confused. The error I get is "Legacy People API has not been used in project 328985958128 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry." The webpage doesn't even load. My code is

```
   if (!req.body.token) return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: 'No access token provided.' })
   const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2
   const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(keys.client_id, keys.client_secret)
   google.options({ auth: oauth2Client });
   const plus = google.plus('v1')
   oauth2Client.setCredentials({
       access_token: req.body.token
   })
   plus.people.get({
       userId: 'me',
       auth: oauth2Client
   }, (error, response) => {
       if (error) 
       console.log(error)
       return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error',error })
       const emails = (response.data || {}).emails
```

Answer (score 2):

### You are using `google.plus('v1')`, which has been [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown)

- Instead you should use

`const service = google.people({version: 'v1', auth: oauth2Client})`

to create a service object.

- To perform a request an additional auhtorization is not required anymore, so:

```
service.people.get({
       userId: 'me'
   }, (error, response) => {
      ...
  })
```

Further information:

- [Creating a service account client with node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)
- [People API quide for node.js](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/nodejs)